# Casting to Serializable in Comparator.comparing

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, comparator

Looking at [`java.util.Comparator` in the JDK 8 source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Comparator.java#Comparator.comparing%28java.util.function.Function%29), I found interesting code:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor){
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        // casting to Serializable?
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
            (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
    }
```

It is pretty clear why we are casting the resulting lambda to `Comparator<T>`, but what is the purpose of casting it to `Serializable`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807912/how-to-serialize-a-lambda  -- and note how Oracle "strongly discourage" the practice: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#serialization   -- where have you found this code?

Comment: @slim the code is from `java.util.Comparator`

Comment: Interesting. My guess is that unless they do this, nobody could make *any* class serializable if it contained a comparator (or they'd have to put in extra effort). But I've never made much use of `serialize()` so will wait to see a more authoritative answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500021/why-does-java-8s-comparator-comparing-cast-the-return-value-to-serializable

Answer (score 3):

That is *making* the lambda serializable from what I know.

Comment: Absolutely right. But what is the purpose?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov I *assume* it has to do with the fact when you serialize some type that *uses* the comparator. Lets say a `TreeSet` or `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: @AndriiAbramov, so apperently this was asked before, just found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642012/why-should-a-comparator-implement-serializable

Comment: Hmm.. Yes. This makes sense. I will close this one as duplicate. Nevertheless, +1!

Comment: @AndriiAbramov you could probably accept it too :)